# Angular 4+ Disable FormControl without disabling the HTML element

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm new to Reactive Forms.

Here is my code where I disable the password from a login form (username and password)

```
this.loginForm.get('password').disable();
```

So next time when the form is submitted the password's validators are not checked.

This is good, but is there a way to disable the `FormControl` without disabling the HTML element?

I want the client to be able to enter the password even if it's not being validated.

Here are the client login steps to understand why I want this behavior:

1. client fills the username
2. on username blur - validate form (just username without password) and check server if the user exists and return the user full name( eg. John Smith). Username field is blurred after the client presses TAB key to go to password field
3. while the HTTP request to validate the username is sent to the server, the client should be allowed to enter the password, even if the password `FormControl` is disabled
4. the username is valid( we received response from the server) and we enable password FormControl `this.loginForm.get('password').enable();`
5. the client press the login button to validate both username and password and make the login.

Comment: Instead of disable(), you could clearValidators(). Then setValidator instead of enable(). I'd like to think there's a cleaner way, but what you seem to be doing is a bit nuanced, so that may be your best option.

Comment: I thought about that, but I wanted to ask first maybe there's an option I might missed

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#clearValidators - here's helpful list of Reactive Forms methods

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled across this problem with a dynamically generated Form that requires explicitly disabling several FormControls to only get a validity value for changed values.

I looked around in the Angular source code and found this:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/62e4acc3d1be412e221b20bdc68618a35ba0c1a8/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_directive.ts#L128

It is code for the `formControl` directive, which disables the DOM element. We could just call the same function to reenable the DOM element after disabling the FormControl.

**So here is what I did:**

*In your template:*

```html
// Template for MyFormComponent
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <my-component #thisComponent
    [formControl]="loginForm.controls['password']"
    (valueChange)="onChange(thisComponent)"
  />
</form>
```

*In TypeScript:*

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  // ...
})
class MyComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  // implement ControlValueAccessor...
}

@Component({
  // ...
})
class MyFormComponent {
  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    password: new FormControl('')
  });

  onChange(valueAccessor: ControlValueAccessor): void {
    this.loginForm.get('password')!.disable();
    if (valueAccessor.setDisabledState) {
      valueAccessor.setDisabledState(false);
    }
  }
}
```

*Remarks:*

You don't need a custom Component which implements ControlValueAccessor as long as the HTMLElement you're using implements the DefaultValueAccessor as can be seen here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/62e4acc3d1be412e221b20bdc68618a35ba0c1a8/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L62-L75